# How would you prove this question?

Tags: geometry

Given ∆ABC with AB>AC.  The bisectors of the interior and exterior angles at A intersect BC at points D and E, respectively.
Prove that (DE/CD)-(DE/DB)=2

Comment: I transfer the quotient of segments into the quotient of areas. Then use the fact $S_{ABC}=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot AC\sin A$ and $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin B}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB>AC$, we know $C$ is between $B$ and $E$.
$\frac{DE}{CD}-\frac{DE}{DB}=\frac{S_{ADE}}{S_{ADC}}-\frac{S_{ADE}}{S_{ABD}}$

$=\frac{AD\cdot AE\sin\angle DAE}{AD\cdot AC\sin\angle DAC}-\frac{AD\cdot AE\sin\angle DAE}{AB\cdot AD\sin\angle BAD}=\frac{AE}{\sin\angle BAD}(\frac{1}{AC}-\frac{1}{AB})$.

Assume $\angle BAD=\alpha$, $\angle B=\beta$. Then $\frac{AE}{AC}=\frac{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha-\beta)}$ and $\frac{AE}{AB}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha-\beta)}$. So you only need to check $\frac{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)-\sin\beta}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)\sin\alpha}=2$.